# Airflow DAG to run 3rd Monday of the month

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I need to schedule my DAG on 11AM on 3rd Monday of the month.
I tried the below sysntax, but it is not working:

**dag = DAG(
Path(**file**).stem,
default_args=default_args,
start_date=days_ago(1),
schedule_interval="0 11 * * 1#4"
)**

Answer (score 3):

Airflow only executes a task when the time window for the particular task has passed, i.e. the task scheduled for the 3rd monday of April will be executed on the 3rd monday of May. However, due to your start_date parameter ('days_ago(1)'), not enough time has passed between the start_date and now for a task to be executed. So to run the task that is supposed to span the time range between 3rd mondays of April and May, the 'start_date' should be before 11am of the 3rd monday of April. Then once the current time has passed 11am of the 3rd monday of May the task should be executed.

On another note (probably a typo), but the cron expression you are using will resolve to the 4th monday of the month, so you are looking for: "0 11 * * 1#3".

Answer (score 0):

3rd monday will be : schedule_interval="0 11 * * 1#3"

and for 4th monday it will be : schedule_interval="0 11 * * 1#4"

After # 1,2,3,4,5 is meant for 1st , 2nd , 3rd , 4th , 5th week of the respective weekend